# how to draw polyline of multiple colors

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, polyline

i am retrieving latitudes & longitudes from mysql db and drawing a polyline to join the points. my point is that i have different types of traffic,namely normal,low,medium and high,,, and  the polyline color must be according to traffic type. for example when "type" is "high" in db..the polyline must show red for a particular coordinate and after that it must return to normal color i.e; "green". and iam not able to do this

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
   <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
       <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>

       <link href="AboutUs.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

       <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCUqr_f2oJMPNcy4JopcjLNQD9YkVQ7JUc"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       //<![CDATA[

      var customIcons = {
      normal: {
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png'
      },
      low: {
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png'
      },
      medium: {
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png'
      },
      high: {
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png'
      }
      };

     function load() {
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.232559, 57.495548),
       zoom: 13,
       mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {
      var xml = data.responseXML;
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
       var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
       var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon
       });
       bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
       }
      });



    downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {  
      var xml = data.responseXML;
      var lat_lng = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");






      //Initialize the Path Array
      var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

      //Initialize the Direction Service
      var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

      //Set the Path Stroke Color
      var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#00ffff'});

      //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
      for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
        if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {


            var src = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(lat_lng[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                        parseFloat(lat_lng[i].getAttribute("lng")));


            var des = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(lat_lng[i + 1].getAttribute("lat")),
                        parseFloat(lat_lng[i + 1].getAttribute("lng")));


            service.route({
                origin: src,
                destination: des,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                        poly.setPath(path);
                    }
                }
              });
          }
       }

     });


    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
         request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
         callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>
```

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="Images/Banner-TE.jpg" alt="Traffic Mgt Website">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar">
       <div id="nav">
            <ul>  
                <li><a href="Home.html"><img src="Images/Home5.jpg"></a></li>


                <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="content">
        <h3>Google Map</h3>



  <div id="map" style="width: 1024px; height: 1024px"></div>
```

this is an image of my db
[image: Database]

this is my map
[image]

Comment: So node A is 'High', and node B is 'Low'. What colour is the path?

Comment: What have you tried? how do you include the traffic level data in the xml generated by phpsqlajax_genxml3.php?

Comment: @Strawberry thats the issue, i want the line to be red from point A to B and green from B to C to denote high from A to B and low for B - C

Comment: @Shadow the traffic data are gathered from a mob app..then passed an algorithm on it and save it in the db, it automatically save the traffic "Type" based on the algoritm

Answer (score 0):

You're already using multiple [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline#example), you can set their respective colors using the `.color()`. Note that `color` will need `int` value in ARGB format

Comment: i need to change the color of the polyline, not  the marker after the different markers

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant Polyline (as indicated on the referenced URL).